# Pointing a derived smart pointer to a stack object returned by base reference

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

I have a problem. I'd like to point shared_ptrs to objects that are stored in a class. In the code there is a Holder::getSomething() function that returns a reference to a base. I'd like to cast that to the derived b_ptr. Here's the code:

```
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

class A{
public:
    int a;

    A() : a(0){}
    virtual ~A(){}
};

class B : public A {
    public:
    bool b;

B() : A(){ b = false; }
};

class Holder{
public: 
    B arr[1];

    // there's an A ref here, not B, because i'll have a boatload of deriveds. 
    A& getSomething(){
        return arr[0];
    }

    Holder(){
        arr[0] = B();
    }
};

int main(){ 

Holder h;

shared_ptr<B> b_ptr;

// b_ptr = something_alien_here(h.getSomething());

return 0;
};
```

I know ( and by "know" i mean i have an uneducated guess ) that i should use dynamic_(pointer_?)cast but i cant find/figure out the right syntax.

Comment: If you are sure `getSomething` really returns a reference to `B`, then `b_ptr.reset(static_cast<B*>(&h.getSomething());`. However: a) if you do know that, then why don't you just return `B&` in the first place, and b) why `shared_ptr`? It'll try to `delete` the pointer when it goes out of scope, which exhibits undefined behavior (and will likely crash) since the pointer wasn't allocated with `new`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole point of a shared pointer is that its ref counted, and destructs 
what it points to when the last one go out of scope. You don't want that to happen 
to a member object of another class, since that is undefined behaviour.

in short; don't do that.

Comment: why do you need a pointer in the first place? wont a reference work?

Answer (score 0):

If you can guarantee that `h` will live longer than `b_ptr`, then you can use the borrowing constructor of `shared_ptr`, together with a cast:

```
Holder h;

std::shared_ptr<B> b_ptr(std::shared_ptr<B>(),
                         &static_cast<B&>(h.getSomething()));
```

Now `b_ptr` shares ownership with the temporary, empty shared pointer, which has the effect of *never* calling the deleter for `B`. This is why it is now *your* responsibility to guarantee that the pointee exists for at least as long as the shared pointer may be dereferenced.